# Finding the grave of Lin Zhao

Tags: china, locate-this

I would like to visit the grave of Chinese dissident [Lin Zhao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lin_Zhao). She was buried in her hometown of Suzhou on mainland China. How can I get to her grave? Can someone please point me in the right direction as to where I can locate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.scmp.com/news/china/article/1225885/remembrance-dissident-lin-zhao-obstructed-45th-execution-anniversary), she was buried on "southern slope of Mount Lingyan". Looking at a map, Lingyan shan seems to be quite small, so it shouldn't be too hard to find. But it is a sensitive area and it seems that visiting, especially around the anniversary of her execution (29 April), might be obstructed by the police.